# How does your proficiency bonus apply to attacks while wild shaped?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, proficiency

I understand that the druid uses his or the beast's proficiency when wild shaping and using skills or saving throws because it is specified in the book.
But how about the creature's attacks?
For example the polar bear has an attack bonus with his claws of +7, which is strength +5, plus its proficiency bonus +2.
But a 5th level characters proficiency bonus is +3, so if he/she used their proficiency bonus it would be strength +5, plus proficiency +3 making the attack bonus +8.
Is this right?

Comment: Related to (but not the same as) ["Which proficiency bonus does a Wild Shaped Druid use for poisons and other save DCs?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86935/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### No, you use the creature's proficiency bonus on its attacks.

The [Wild Shape](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Classes:Druid#toc_6) class feature describes which statistics are kept, and which statistics are changed, you use when you use this ability.

> Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the beast, but you retain your alignment, personality, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores. You also retain all of your skill and saving throw proficiencies, in addition to gaining those of the creature.

According to this ability, you only you use the druid's proficiency bonus on skills and saving throws. Attack rolls are neither skills nor saving throws, so it does not apply. Otherwise your "game Statistics", such as proficiency bonus on attacks, are replaced.

I also found a relevant [tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/558355703530672128) by Jeremy Crawford, one of the game's designers:

> The intent is that the druid uses the bonus in the beast's stat block for any proficiency the druid lacks.

Unless the druid is proficient with claws, bites, or other types of the creature's attacks, it seems that there is no cause to apply the druid's proficiency bonus.

Remember, the [lack of an explicit "no" does not translate to a "yes"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637). If druids could retain their proficiency bonus on attack rolls when wild shaped, then the rules would say so, but that is not the case.

Comment: ...so what you're saying is a lizardfolk druid bites with proficiency...

Answer (score -8):

### You are correct.

It would be your proficiency bonus because that is showing how skilled your character is. So it would be the creatures strength modifier plus your proficiency bonus.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77381/discussion-on-answer-by-perrin-tealeaf-how-does-your-proficiency-bonus-apply-to).